# Preserving leading 0's in string - number - string conversion

Tags: string, vba, excel, type-conversion

I am working on a macro for a document-tracking sheet at work.  I use a button that prompts the user to enter in the document number and I'd like to specify a default number based on the following numbering convention.  The first two characters of the document number are the latter two year digits (15 in this case), then there is a "-" followed by a five digit serialization.

My current code looks at the last-entered document and increments those last 5 characters, but chops off any leading zeroes, which I want to keep. This is an extraction of the code to generate this default number (assuming the variable "prevNCRF" is the previous document name found in the doc):

```
    Sub codeChunkTester()

    Dim prevNCRF, defNCRFNum As String
    Dim NCRFNumAr() As String

    'pretend like we found this in the sheet.
    prevNCRF = "15-00100"

    'split the string into "15" and "00100" and throw those into an array.
    NCRFNumAr() = Split(prevNCRF, "-")

    'reconstruct the number by reusing the first part and dash, then converting
    'the "00100" to a number with Val(), adding 1, then back to a string with CStr().
    defNCRFNum = NCRFNumAr(0) & "-" & CStr(Val(NCRFNumAr(1)) + 1)

    'message box shows "15-101" rather than "15-00101" as I had hoped.
    MsgBox (defNCRFNum)

    End Sub
```

So can anyone help me preserve those zeroes?  I suppose I could include a loop that checks the length of the string and adds a leading zero until there are 5 characters, but perhaps there's a better way...

Comment: Converting `"00100"` to a number converts it to `100`. Converting `100` to a string converts it to `"100"`. What made you expect anything else? You need to pad the string with zeroes if you want `"00100"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting `"00100"` to a `Double` using `Val` turned it into `100`, so `CStr(100)` returns `"100"` as it should.

You need to format the string to what you want it to look like:

```
defNCRFNum = NCRFNumAr(0) & "-" & Format(Val(NCRFNumAr(1)) + 1, "00000")
```

If you need to parameterize the length of the string, you can use the `String` function to generate the format string:

```
Const digits As Integer = 5

Dim formatString As String
formatString = String(digits, "0")

defNCRFNum = NCRFNumAr(0) & "-" & Format(Val(NCRFNumAr(1)) + 1, formatString)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is that loop solution I mentioned above.  If anyone's got something better, I'm all ears!

```
prevNCRF = "15-00100"
NCRFNumAr() = Split(prevNCRF, "-")
zeroAdder = CStr(Val(NCRFNumAr(1)) + 1)

'loop: everytime the zeroAdder string is not 5 characters long, 
'put a zero in front of it.
Do Until Len(zeroAdder) = 5
    zeroAdder = "0" & zeroAdder
Loop

defNCRFNum = NCRFNumAr(0) & "-" & zeroAdder
MsgBox (defNCRFNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
defNCRFNum = NCRFNumAr(0) & "-" & Format(CStr(Val(NCRFNumAr(1)) + 1), String(Len(NCRFNumAr(1)), "0"))
```